# Failed to establish a new connection Errno 111 Connection Refused?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, posthog

I am trying to get the web, db and redis services running via docker compose but my web container keeps going down. And on inspecting the logs, i see :- `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc998b43070>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

To Reproduce the issue :-

```
1. git clone https://github.com/PostHog/posthog && cd posthog and run docker-compose up -d
2. This is my docker compose file :-

services:
    db:
        container_name: posthog_db
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: posthog
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: posthog
            POSTGRES_USER: posthog
        image: postgres:alpine
        volumes:
            - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    redis:
        container_name: posthog_redis
        image: redis:alpine
    web:
        container_name: posthog_web
        depends_on:
            - db
            - redis
        environment:
            SKIP_SERVICE_VERSION_REQUIREMENTS: '1'
            DISBALE_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT: 'true'
            SECURE_COOKIES: 'false'
            DATABASE_URL: postgres://posthog:posthog@db:5432/posthog
            REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/
            SECRET_KEY: "eda6e05b653466fd47892f7b26a253eeda17e2df1d932c8022b6f0ab"
        image: posthog/posthog:latest
        links:
            - db:db
            - redis:redis
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
            - 80:8000
volumes:
    postgres-data:
version: '2'
```

On inspecting the logs, this is what i am seeing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
conn = connection.create_connection(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
raise err
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
httplib_response = self._make_request(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 353, in connect
conn = self._new_conn()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7e78794190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
resp = conn.urlopen(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
retries = retries.increment(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7e78794190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 21, in
main()
File "manage.py", line 17, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 413, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/posthog/code/ee/management/commands/migrate_clickhouse.py", line 41, in handle
self.migrate(CLICKHOUSE_HTTP_URL, options)
File "/home/posthog/code/ee/management/commands/migrate_clickhouse.py", line 44, in migrate
database = Database(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/infi/clickhouse_orm/database.py", line 111, in init
self.db_exists = self._is_existing_database()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/infi/clickhouse_orm/database.py", line 418, in _is_existing_database
r = self._send("SELECT count() FROM system.databases WHERE name = '%s'" % self.db_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/infi/clickhouse_orm/database.py", line 369, in _send
r = self.request_session.post(self.db_url, params=params, data=data, stream=stream, timeout=self.timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 590, in post
return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7e78794190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

*Environment*

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS && Ubuntu 16.04

Docker version 20.10.9, build c2ea9bc && Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe

docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe && docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown

Comment: That error message looks like it's trying to connect to `https://localhost:8443`; that's not going to be either the PostgreSQL or Redis containers you show, both of which use separate non-HTTP protocols.  Is there another container that needs to be part of this setup?  Scanning the backtrace, do you maybe need to set a `CLICKHOUSE_HTTP_URL` environment variable?